# Incorrect dimensions error while using cv.glmnet function in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet, lasso-regression

```
cv.out.lasso  <- cv.glmnet(x[train, ], y[train], alpha=1)
```

I am trying to use `cv.glmnet` , but I am getting this error:

> Error in x[train, ] : incorrect number of dimensions.

i checked the dimensions of the `matrix x[train, ]` and also the length of y. The columns of the matrix equals the length of the y vector.

I am not getting what's wrong here. Can someone please help?